# unknown table in multi delte statement

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I need to make a stored procedure that would modify data about an user from the database,I got a unknown table in multi delte statement,i've no idea what is wrong,can someone help?

I've tried changing the code ,deleting some parts,did'nt actually work

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `modifyUser`(userIDtodelete int,
    name varchar(50),
    surname varchar(50),
    email varchar(50),
    dateOfBirth date,
    username varchar(50),
    placeOfBirth varchar(50),
    photo mediumblob)
BEGIN
    if user.UserID=userIDtodelete then delete user.userID from user
        where user.UserID=userIDtodelete;
        insert into user(Name,Surname,DateOfBirth,PlaceOfBirth,Email,Username,Photo)
            values(name,surname,dateOfBirth,placeOfBirth,email,username,photo);
    end if;
END

Operation failed: There was an error while applying the SQL script to the database.
ERROR 1109: Unknown table 'userid' in MULTI DELETE
```

Comment: "delete user.userID" is not valid for your database. is there such a table..?

Comment: Perhaps "delete user" without ".userID" works, if there is such a table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change "delete user.userID from user" to "delete from user".

Edit: It could help to think that you are deleting a whole row (not just a column) from the table.